# Spark: how to kill the spark-submit process

Tags: apache-spark

How do I kill a running spark-submit process? I'm trying to write a script to do this but I don't know how to get the Yarn application ID.

Comment: Could you share any attempts you made?

Answer (score 0):

$ ps | grep java

this will show some process with note the PID value lets say the value is 848484

$ kill -9 848484

this will kill the process

or in your process at the end of action you can add awaittermination unless you want to run process in background

awaitTermination - It internally uses some condition variable which keeps a check on whether stop() was invoked explicitly in code or the application terminated (Ctrl+C).

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach to kill a spark-submitted app is to kill the application that is in yarn. So, run:

1. `yarn application -list` => To see all the applications that are running in yarn.
2. Find your application Id from output resulted from step 1.
3. Kill the yarn application with `yarn application -kill <appID>`

Also, if you want to see the yarn logs, you can use: `yarn logs -applicationId <appID>`